# Setting Up Latex on MacOs using VSCode

Tags: installing, mac, macos

Good afternoon everyone,
I am currently resetting my mac and reinstalling everything in a clean way.
I would love to have guidance here if possible.
I currently installed TexLive and TextDist but now i am guiding myself with this :
https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Install

If anyone could explain to me this section :

> Setting PATH environment variable
>
> After installing TeX Live, you must add the directory of TeX Live
> binaries to your PATH environment variable except on Windows. See the
> official document. LaTeX Workshop never touches the variable. If VS
> Code cannot find executables of TeX, it means that the setting of your
> system is broken. For the ways of setting environment variables on
> Windows, see link or link. On macOS and Linux, see the documentation
> by the rbenv dev team. Very detailed information is also available on
> stackoverflow for macOS.
>
> Notice that you have to restart VS Code and the operating system after
> changing the variable.
>
> If you can not fix the setting of your system, you can also override
> PATH with the env property of LaTeX tools in LaTeX recipes.
>
> Notice that, to set the PATH environment variable for VS Code Remote
> Development, you usually have to edit .bash_profile or .profile
> instead of .bashrc. See the document for WSL and an issue for Remote
> SSH.
>
> If you want to know about environment variable itself, please read
> Wikipedia and stackexchange.

I do not really understand how it is important and what to do if anyone could help here !

Comment: If you're willing to use a different editor/front-end, then the simplest way is to install MacTeX, which includes TeXLive. When the installation is complete, everything "just works" -- no environment variables or path values to set manually. MacTeX includes the very configurable TeXShop editor/front-end (but you may want to just leave it with the default settings until such time as you have need to change any of those).

Comment: I second @murray's suggestion to go with [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html). MacTeX *is* TeXLive, with a couple of nice utilities that make installing and maintaining the TeX distribution a breeze under MacOS.

Comment: The wiki page you cite links to https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html, which has a section "Post-install: setting PATH". You will basically have to add the TeX Live installation path into your `.bashrc` or `.profile` accordingly with the correct format.